# In a Warcraft 3 LAN game, is there any way to save progress more than once per player?

Tags: warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

When playing a WC3 LAN match, each player can save the game once, after which the 'Save game' option in the menu is disabled.  I fail to see the point in this, and would really like to be able to save more often.  This is especially true when one of us has a less-than-reliable connection and may be dropped from the game from time to time.

I have found one workaround, and that is that if we save the game, end the game, then reload/rejoin the saved game the option to save will once again be available (but, of course, only one time, and then the process must be repeated).  While this is better than nothing, it can get awfully tedious and annoying to have to do this every time we want to save the game.

Has anybody found any way to get around this limitation?  I'm wondering if maybe there's a special hack I don't know about, or maybe some less tedious workaround.

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need to save so much in a LAN game ?

Comment: @Bluetrin some of the custom maps, like for example the final fantasy rpg maps, take really long to complete. Must...level all...jobs...

Comment: i believe the formulae is one save per player PER GAME. So after a save, if you quit and reload, you should be fine

Comment: Ender states the truth here. The limitation is there because spam-saving could cause Starcraft/Warcraft games to crash, and abusing of this would be possible in online games. However, loading a game when saving it will reset the "limit"

Comment: I already mentioned in my post that I knew you could 'reset' this limitation by reloading, but it's incredibly troublesome.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments:

The one save is per *play* rather than per map. So after saving, quit, reload and you'll get your save slot back.

This was/is an anti-spam measure because too much saving could cause the game to crash.

While you already know about this, it is your only way.

Comment: If they're really trying to prevent "save-spamming", then they could at the very least simply implemented a delay before making "Save game" available again (maybe a few minutes or so), rather than disabling it for the remainder of the session.  Last night my friend and I had played hours into an RPG type game when my game crashed unexpectedly, and thus lost all of our progress.

Comment: I'm going to try poking around a bit more to see if I can find a way maybe nobody else has found yet.  It may be a waste of time, but I'm still not ready to accept that there is NO other way...

Answer (score 2):

The [UnlimitedSave](http://www.d3scene.com/forum/warcraft-3-hacks/87886-unlimitedsave.html) mod will do this now.

From the description:

> This disables the limitation that prevents you from saving more than once. Only downside is, everybody needs to do it, otherwise the client will disconnect if someone saves for the second time.

Comment: This looks incredibly promising.  Thank you so much for providing this answer for me.  I don't know when I'll have a chance to try that mod but I'll certainly try it next time I play with friends.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be to use GProxy++, which prevented war3 from dropping disconnected players, and allowed them to get back into the game without having to load a save.

I hosted with it for some time when I used to play DotA, and it worked well.
I didn't try it for long, yet, since using Listchecker was "more convinient".
Most disconnections were ragequit anyway, so it didn't help me that much.

I think it would work for LAN as well as for BNET
Of course, after so much years, I'm not even sure finding some working binaries would be easy now.

I mainly post this so that people are aware such a solution did exist.  Maybe someone will comment my answer with links to an actually working solution ?

Here are some articles about it :
https://www.ghostpp.com/wiki/index.php?title=GProxy%2B%2B
https://www.entgaming.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=552